# Protected question and Association bonus bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, protected-questions, privileges

I currently have 101 reputation for this site (Due to the association bonus), however I am unable to post an answer on this protected question.

[Produce the number 2014 without any numbers in your source code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

[image]

I have the ability to vote up (15 rep), comment (50 rep) however I am unable to provide an answer.

Comment: I have an [open ticket on meta.stackoverflow for this very issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210481/153542) because I don't feel that the message received is clear enough for this particular case.

Comment: This question was also answered [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7090/45600)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign): [What is a protected question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

The assoc bonus does not count for this purpose.

Comment: Why doesn't it count?

Comment: So you have to know at least a bit a site before you post there.