# Multiple bugs in my profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I recently registered on this site, and I encountered two bugs,

First is that I cannot see a link to meta site on my profile page

[image]

And secondly, I earned association rep of 100, so the total score was 101, but I was not able [to answer a community protected question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21835/26389) unless I was voted up, is that status by design or 100 rep isn't considered to answer protected questions?

I was able to answer only when I was upvoted once

---

Ok, seems like [Related question link provided me an answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/protected-question-and-association-bonus-bug?rq=1) but the first issue isn't solved, I had to type meta word before codegolf to get here

Comment: You created your account an hour ago on the main site, your account on meta was probably not yet created (because it is cached separately, I think).

Comment: I believe that the rules are that the association bonus is *not* included in the protected question block. That is, if you need 10, then the association bonus means you need 110 rep to answer it.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes I got that from the Related Questions list after I posted and hence I've linked the same question in my answer ...

Comment: I didn't click the links (on mobile).

Comment: @KyleKanos its fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Meta account is only created after you visit the meta site, so the link only appears after you do so.

The association bonus does not count towards the privilege to answer protected questions:

> <sup>https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user</sup>
>   Note that one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. The association bonus does not count.

Answer (score 0):

The site navigation to meta has changed as of the [new topbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198613/13), where you click on the top-left site selector to get to meta. [Many people dislike not being able to change to meta with one click, though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198758/13)

(This is separate to the issue of not seeing the "Meta User" link in your profile page, of course, which is already addressed by plannapus's comment.)